# How to upload file using multer and store details in database in mean rest app and retrieve it from angular.js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, express, multer

I am uploading file through my rest mean application, but i am not able to retrieve it back from backend . how do i retrieve it,
Here is **upload code**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, mongoose.Types.ObjectId() + '-' + file.originalname);
          }
  });
  var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',10);
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
    console.log(req.files);
    var images =[];
    for(var i=0; i<req.files.length; i++){
      images[i]=req.files[i].path;
    }
        var newalbum = new albummodel({
           image:images
        });
        newalbum.save(function(err, albm) {
           if(err) {
              res.json({success: false, msg: 'can't store.'});
           } else {
            console.log(albm);
          }
        });
    if(err) {
      return res.end("Error uploading file.");
    }
    res.end("File is uploaded");
  });
```

Here is my **retrieve code**

```
albummodel.findOne({_id:req.params.id},function(err, docs){
    res.json(docs);
 })
```

Comment: Are you able to save multiple images to folder and respective imagepaths to mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

This whole discussion help you. Please refer it.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3079